# How to join two XML files with a matching node

Tags: php, xml, ajax, xslt

I need to find a way to join two XML files when they have a matching node. From what I gather this could be accomplished with many different languages... is there a PHP or an AJAX way to do this?  From other posts on SO I see XSLT solutions.. that I dont really get. Is this the best/preferred method?  If so, know of any helpful XSLT tutorials?

For example XML-1 is like :

```
<FOO>
    </A>
    </B>
    </C>
    </D>
</FOO>
```

and XML-2 :

```
<FOO>    
    </B>
    </E>
</FOO>
```

What would be the best approach for checking where `<B>==<B>` then add `<E>`

#### Update

Well I cant get this to work with my hypothetical example and thought I would update with what I am really doing to see if anyone can help me figure this.  I have tried the methods from below and others I have found on SO with no luck.

The real schema is like :

file1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DATA>
  <ITEM>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE>simple</PRODUCT_TYPE>
    <STYLE_COLOR>1524740007</STYLE_COLOR>
    <SHORT_DESCRIPTION>Black Shoe</SHORT_DESCRIPTION>
    <CLASS_NAME>FOOTWEAR</CLASS_NAME>
    <STATUS>Disabled</STATUS>
  </ITEM>
 ...
</DATA>
```

file2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="merge.xsl" ?>
<DATA>
  <ITEM>
    <STYLE_COLOR>1524740007</STYLE_COLOR>
    <NEXT_ARRIVAL>2011-08-05</NEXT_ARRIVAL>
  </ITEM>
  ....
</DATA>
```

What I need to figure out is to have a new XML file generated that would merge these nodes with identical SYTLE_COLOR and look like:

```
<DATA>
  <ITEM>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE>simple</PRODUCT_TYPE>
    <STYLE_COLOR>1524740007</STYLE_COLOR>
    <SHORT_DESCRIPTION>Black Shoe</SHORT_DESCRIPTION>
    <CLASS_NAME>FOOTWEAR</CLASS_NAME>
    <NEXT_ARRIVAL>2011-08-05</NEXT_ARRIVAL>
    <STATUS>Disabled</STATUS>
  </ITEM>
```

I tried creating a merge.xsl that looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="with" select="'file-2.xml'" />
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="scene">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      <xsl:variable name="info" select="document($with)/DATA/ITEM[STYLE_COLOR=current()/STYLE_COLOR]/." />
      <xsl:for-each select="$info/*">
        <xsl:if test="name()!='STYLE_COLOR'">
          <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

I also tried a merge like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="input2" select="document('file-2.xml')/DATA/ITEM"/>
    <xsl:template match="STYLE_COLOR">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$input2/*[name()=name(current())]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$input2/*"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Neither of these methods are working..  sorry XSLT is very new to me so I am not sure what I am doing and would really appreciate some hand holding on this one.

Comment: XSLT is one way to go. "Is this the best/preferred method?" It depends by your experience and your requirements. Is your xml really that simple??

Comment: Does the order of tag matter? For example, `D` must come at the end?

Comment: Please also indicate the XSLT version you can take into consideration.

Comment: Order of tag is not important.. I think I have to use 1.0

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a very simple solution that is also parameterized and flexible. This solution uses the XSLT `document()` function and is also based on the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern. Detailed explanation is provided at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the original transform slightly modified to adapt the new requirements. The merge is performed by checking against *file2.xml* elements. For the current ITEM in *file1*, a children ITEM in *file2* will be merged **only** if not present in the *file1*.

---

[XSLT 1.0]

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="input2" select="document('test_input2.xml')/DATA"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ITEM">
        <xsl:variable name="item" select="
            $input2/ITEM[STYLE_COLOR=current()/STYLE_COLOR]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="ITEM" select="."/>

        <xsl:if test="$item">
            <xsl:copy>

                <xsl:for-each select="$item/*">
                    <xsl:if test="count($ITEM/*[name()=name(current())])=0">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>

                <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied on this `input1.xml`:

```
<DATA>
  <ITEM>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE>simple</PRODUCT_TYPE>
    <STYLE_COLOR>1524740007</STYLE_COLOR>
    <SHORT_DESCRIPTION>Black Shoe</SHORT_DESCRIPTION>
    <CLASS_NAME>FOOTWEAR</CLASS_NAME>
    <STATUS>Disabled</STATUS>
  </ITEM>
  <ITEM>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE>simple</PRODUCT_TYPE>
    <STYLE_COLOR>1524740008</STYLE_COLOR>
    <SHORT_DESCRIPTION>Black Shoe</SHORT_DESCRIPTION>
    <CLASS_NAME>FOOTWEAR</CLASS_NAME>
    <STATUS>Disabled</STATUS>
  </ITEM>
  <ITEM>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE>simple</PRODUCT_TYPE>
    <STYLE_COLOR>777</STYLE_COLOR>
    <SHORT_DESCRIPTION>Black Shoe</SHORT_DESCRIPTION>
    <CLASS_NAME>FOOTWEAR</CLASS_NAME>
    <STATUS>Disabled</STATUS>
  </ITEM>
</DATA>
```

and `input2.xml` to merge, produces:

```
<DATA>
  <ITEM>
    <STYLE_COLOR>1524740007</STYLE_COLOR>
    <NEXT_ARRIVAL>2011-08-05</NEXT_ARRIVAL>
    <CLASS_NAME>XXX</CLASS_NAME>
    <OTHER>YYY</OTHER>
  </ITEM>
  <ITEM>
    <STYLE_COLOR>1524740008</STYLE_COLOR>
    <NEXT_ARRIVAL>2011-08-05</NEXT_ARRIVAL>
  </ITEM>
</DATA>
```

produces:

```
<DATA>
   <ITEM>
      <NEXT_ARRIVAL>2011-08-05</NEXT_ARRIVAL>
      <OTHER>YYY</OTHER>
      <PRODUCT_TYPE>simple</PRODUCT_TYPE>
      <STYLE_COLOR>1524740007</STYLE_COLOR>
      <SHORT_DESCRIPTION>Black Shoe</SHORT_DESCRIPTION>
      <CLASS_NAME>FOOTWEAR</CLASS_NAME>
      <STATUS>Disabled</STATUS>
   </ITEM>
   <ITEM>
      <NEXT_ARRIVAL>2011-08-05</NEXT_ARRIVAL>
      <PRODUCT_TYPE>simple</PRODUCT_TYPE>
      <STYLE_COLOR>1524740008</STYLE_COLOR>
      <SHORT_DESCRIPTION>Black Shoe</SHORT_DESCRIPTION>
      <CLASS_NAME>FOOTWEAR</CLASS_NAME>
      <STATUS>Disabled</STATUS>
   </ITEM>
</DATA>
```

Notice that:

- the transform *does not* override existing elements for a given ITEM, just copy the missing ones
- ITEM in `input1.xml` is copied in output only if has a match in `input2.xml`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. please pardon my response time as I am about to head out for much needed vacation and it will be a bit before I can dive in.

Comment: I worked with this for a while but it is not happening for me.  I updated my question so that it is a more "real" example

Comment: @Sushi, the initial example was too simple. I've updated my answer to fulfill new requirements based on the updated question. See if it's what you were searching for.

Comment: Oh thanks empo! That did the trick... one more question though.  The XML lost all of its formatting and now all the nodes are just mashed together.. any idea why that would be?

Comment: Do you refer to indentation? That's probably due to the way you are transforming data.  You are using .NET? Can you be more specific about that point.

Comment: Sorry to not be more specific.. it is because I dont understand.  Yes I mean indentation.  .NET ?  I am confused.  I am just trying to view it in the browser by going right to file-1.xml .  In file-1 I reference the merge with <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="merge.xsl" ?>

Comment: ah! XSLT processors does not always follow the setting in `xsl:output` (indent="yes"). Also, inner XSLT processors of browsers are known to not fully compliant with XSLT 1.0. You might also get different results according  to the used browser. Do you really need to transform your data using this kind of approach? You should consider of using Saxon otherwise.

Comment: If you are not bound for some reasons to the browsers or other kind of application, __use Saxon indeed__.

Comment: hmm ok I will see what I can figure out, Saxon is new to me so I have some homework

Comment: Just install and try it once. That's enough to get used with it :D

Comment: Thanks so much for all of your help empo

Comment: I gave you the bounty and accept but can you answer one more question please. If I want the results to be just the matching records in file 1 and file2 (similar to an inner join in SQL) what would need to be changed in the XSLT?

Comment: Question edited to include in the produced output only matched ITEM. Hope I've understood the question in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation** (`c:/temp/file1.xml` and `c:/temp/file2.xml` are as provided in the question):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pDoc1" select="'file:///c:/temp/file1.xml'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vDoc1" select="document($pDoc1)"/>

 <xsl:param name="pDoc2" select="'file:///c:/temp/file2.xml'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vDoc2" select="document($pDoc2)"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$vDoc1/node()"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ITEM">
  <ITEM>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>

   <xsl:apply-templates select=
     "$vDoc2/*/ITEM
               [STYLE_COLOR = current()/STYLE_COLOR]
                /node()[not(self::STYLE_COLOR)]
     "/>
  </ITEM>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any XML document (not used / ignored), produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<DATA>
   <ITEM xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <PRODUCT_TYPE>simple</PRODUCT_TYPE>
      <STYLE_COLOR>1524740007</STYLE_COLOR>
      <SHORT_DESCRIPTION>Black Shoe</SHORT_DESCRIPTION>
      <CLASS_NAME>FOOTWEAR</CLASS_NAME>
      <STATUS>Disabled</STATUS>
      <NEXT_ARRIVAL>2011-08-05</NEXT_ARRIVAL>
   </ITEM> ...
</DATA>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **First we process (apply templates to) the nodes of the first XML document**.
2. **The identity rule/template copies every node as is**.
3. **There is a single template that overrides the identity rule**. This template matches any element named `ITEM`. It creates an element also named `ITEM`, then processes all children nodes and this results in copying them by the identity template. Finally, all nodes that are children of any `ITEM` element from the second XML document whose `STYLE_COLOR` child has the same string value as the string value of the `STYLE_COLOR` child of the current (matched) element are also copied (by applying templates to them and as result of the selection and execution of the identity template), with the exception of the `STYLE_COLOR` child itself.
4. **Do note that the filepaths of the two pats are passed as parameters to the transformation**, which makes it more flexible and able to work with any two XML files -- without any modification. We use the XSLT [**`document()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#function-document) function to load and parse these two documents so that they can be processed by the xslt transformation.
5. **Do note that no `xsl:for-each` or `xsl:if` or any other XSLT conditional instructions are used** in this transformation. This results in simpler and easier to maintain and understand code.
6. **Finally, note the use and overriding of the identity rule/template. This is the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern**.

Comment: Good solution. Just note that by this transform the merged file will also add to the source file elements that are already present in the source.

Comment: @empo: I know. The OP hasn't specified any replacement or non-replacement policy and the solution produces the expected results with his data. I don't want to be speculating about what replacement policy he considers the right one -- doing this has 50%+ chance of being wrong. If the OP specifies his replacement requirements I will then modify the solution to reflect them exactly.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre!  I am still having the issue with the nodes all being removed after the process.  Do you also suggest that I need to use Saxon for this?  I was hoping to avoid that if possible..

Comment: @Sushi K: You need to use an XSLT processor -- be it Saxon or another one. It is absolutely not serious to use a browser as an XSLT processor during XSLT development. If this is your main problem, I suggest that you re-tag the question to "xsltprocessors". From the XSLT point of view, you have been given two correct solutions. Not being able to use them is *not* an XSLT problem.

Comment: Got it, thanks for all of your help and sorry to be daft. This is VERY new to me (obviously).

Answer (score -1):

XSLT is quite powerful, however I must admit that I'm not that fluently with it, so will give you a sugestion for a manual transformation:

```
print "<FOOCONTAINER>\n";
readfile($xml1file);
readfile($xml2file);
print "</FOOCONTAINER>\n";
```

Anything else you can easily accomplish within the further processing as this is XML.

**Edit:** This works only for the first XML offered by the OP.