# Join or merge two XML files with a matching node

Tags: php, xml, merge

How can I merge 2 xml records based on a common matching node (the key or in this example: `<id>`), by using php?

1.xml:

```
<record>
   <id>001</id>
   <other_nodes>...</other_nodes>
   ...
</record>
<record>
   <id>002</id>
   ...
</record>
```

2.xml:

```
<record>
   <id>001</id>
   <description>abc</description>
   ...
</record>
<record>
   <id>002</id>
   <description>def</description>
   ...
    </record>
```

Merged.xml:

```
<record>
    <id>001</id>
    <other_nodes></other_nodes>
    <description>abc</description>
    ...
</record>
<record>
    <id>002</id>
    <description>def</description>
    ...
</record>
```

Beside the `<id>`, all nodes in both xml files are different (unique). The aim is to append the ones of 2.xml to 1.xml. (just adding the `<description>` node to 1.xml would also do the job!)

I tried several codings (like nested foreach loops), nothing worked. The best I can do (I tried multiple versions):

(Inspired by [Merge two xml files based on common attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081905/merge-two-xml-files-based-on-common-attribute?rq=1)):

```
$file = ...    
$targetDom = new DOMDocument();
$targetDom->load($file);
$targetXpath = new DOMXpath($targetDom);

$addDom = new DOMDocument();
$addDom->loadXml($file2);
$addXpath = new DOMXpath($addDom);

// copy elements depending on ProductId
foreach ($targetXpath->evaluate('//record') as $record) {
  $productId = $record->id->value;
  foreach ($addXpath->evaluate('//record[id=\"'.$productId.'\"]') as $attribute) {
    $parent_node = $attribute->evaluate('../codename'); //evaluate or xpath? 
    //$record->appendChild($targetDom->importNode($parent_node));
    $newValue = $attribute->description->value;

    //$record->addChild("description", $newValue);
    $element = $dom->createElement('codename', $newValue);
    $record->appendChild($element);

  //$targetDom->documentElement->appendChild(
    //  $targetDom->importNode($parent_node));  
  }
}

$xmlsave = $targetDom->saveXml();
```

Question relative to:
[How to join two XML files with a matching node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364362/how-to-join-two-xml-files-with-a-matching-node)

Comment: a) can XML2 have a record that is not in XML1 and has to be included in the combined XML3?

Comment: Yes, in my case all records of XML2 are different from XML1 (except the `id`).

Comment: What I meant is if there are `id`s in XML2 that are NOT in XML1

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [xsl(t)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rn1bvTYYsCY)

merge.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="mergedoc" select="document($mergesrc)" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="record">
        <xsl:variable name="idmerge" select="id" />
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$mergedoc/records/record[id=$idmerge]/*[not(name()='id')]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

php script:

```
<?php
$src = doc('1.xml');
$processor = new XSLTProcessor;
$processor->importStylesheet( doc('merge.xsl') );
$processor->setParameter('', 'mergesrc', '2.xml');

$result = $processor->transformToDoc($src);
$result->formatOutput=true;
echo $result->savexml();


function doc($srcpath) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->load($srcpath);
    return $doc;
}
```

explaination

```
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
```

the ability to use more than one document is not part of the xslt 1.0 specification. But libxslt supports it via exsl - so we "import" it.

---

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
```

Just something to make the output a bit prettier. Works in conjunction with `$result->formatOutput=true;`. But if you should ever have problems with the whitespaces  ...take a look at these three lines.

---

```
<xsl:param name="mergedoc" select="document($mergesrc)" />
```

here the second document is "loaded and stored in $mergedoc".
$mergesrc itself is a parameter which is set via `$processor->setParameter('', 'mergesrc', '2.xml');`

---

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

basic xsl copy-all template. Every node that doesn't have a more specific template is deep-copied to the result.

---

And now for the fun part, the template matching `record` elements.

```
<xsl:variable name="idmerge" select="id" />
```

stores the value of the id element of the current record element in $idmerge.

```
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
```

We want to copy the contents to the result and start with the contents of the current record element (xsl:apply-templates without select attribute and the copy-all template will do just that).

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$mergedoc/records/record[id=$idmerge]/*[not(name()='id')]" />
```

from the mergedoc (2.xml) select the `record` element that has the same id as the current `record` element "in" 1.xml - which is stored in $idmerge.
Of this record select all child nodes - but not the id element (which has already been provided by the current record element of 1.xml) - and send it to the copy-all template (because there is no more specific template).

Comment: Nice solution and well explained. I got the script to work but it only outputs the original 1.xml and the records of 2.xml seem not to be copied at all.  It seems (by omission) that this line is not executed:  (My $idmergedoc reference should work.) `<xsl:apply-templates select="$mergedoc/ops/record[id=$idmerge]/*[not(name()='id')]" />`