# How can I combine 2 xml files after matching them?

Tags: xml, merge, directory, compare, diff

First XML File

```
<post>
        <ParentProductID>0</ParentProductID>
        <id>24109</id>
        <Title>1423 Saten Gecelik Sabahlık Takım</Title>
        <Content><![CDATA[<b>Ürün Adı :</b><br> 1423 Saten Gecelik Sabahlık Takım]]></Content>
        <SKU>4966522373865</SKU>
        <ProductType>variable</ProductType>
        <BedenGrup>L|M|S</BedenGrup>
        <BoyutGrup></BoyutGrup>
        <Marka></Marka>
        <Cinsiyet></Cinsiyet>
        <RenkGrup>Yeşil</RenkGrup>
        <Stock>749</Stock>
        <kategoriler><![CDATA[Kadın>İç Giyim>Gecelik]]></kategoriler>
        <resim>https://gooxyz.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/sistina-1423.jpeg|https://gooxyz.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/sistina-1423-695.jpeg</resim>
        <RegularPrice></RegularPrice>
        <SalePrice></SalePrice>
    </post>
```

Second XML File

```
 <post>
        <ParentProductID>24109</ParentProductID>
        <id>24110</id>
        <Title>1423 Saten Gecelik Sabahlık Takım</Title>
        <SKU>4966522373965</SKU>
        <ProductType>variable</ProductType>
        <Bedenrn>L</Bedenrn>
        <Cinsiyetrn></Cinsiyetrn>
        <Renkrn>Yeşil</Renkrn>
        <RegularPrice>203.55</RegularPrice>
        <SalePrice>150.07</SalePrice>
        <Price>150.07</Price>
        <Stock>250</Stock>
        <ImageURL></ImageURL>
        <rnkategorileri><![CDATA[Kadın>İç Giyim>Gecelik]]></rnkategorileri>
        <rnetiketleri></rnetiketleri>
    </post>

    <post>
        <ParentProductID>24109</ParentProductID>
        <id>24111</id>
        <Title>1423 Saten Gecelik Sabahlık Takım</Title>
        <SKU>4966522374065</SKU>
        <ProductType>variable</ProductType>
        <Bedenrn>M</Bedenrn>
        <Cinsiyetrn></Cinsiyetrn>
        <Renkrn>Yeşil</Renkrn>
        <RegularPrice>203.55</RegularPrice>
        <SalePrice>150.07</SalePrice>
        <Price>150.07</Price>
        <Stock>249</Stock>
        <ImageURL></ImageURL>
        <rnkategorileri><![CDATA[Kadın>İç Giyim>Gecelik]]></rnkategorileri>
        <rnetiketleri></rnetiketleri>
    </post>
```

I want to XML file (matching id to parent product id)

```
<post>
        <ParentProductID>0</ParentProductID>
        <id>24109</id>
        <Title>1423 Saten Gecelik Sabahlık Takım</Title>
        <Content><![CDATA[<b>Ürün Adı :</b><br> 1423 Saten Gecelik Sabahlık Takım]]></Content>
        <SKU>4966522373865</SKU>
        <Stock>749</Stock>
        <kategoriler><![CDATA[Kadın>İç Giyim>Gecelik]]></kategoriler>
        <resim1>https://gooxyz.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/sistina-1423.jpeg</resim1><resim2>https://gooxyz.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/sistina-1423-695.jpeg</resim2>
        <RegularPrice>203.55</RegularPrice>
        <SalePrice>150.07</SalePrice>


 <varyants>
    <varyant>
    <bedenrn>M</bedenrn>
    <Renkrn>Yeşil</Renkrn>
    <Stock>249</Stock>
    </varyant>
    <varyant>
    <bedenrn>L</bedenrn>
    <Renkrn>Yeşil</Renkrn>
    <Stock>249</Stock>
    </varyant>
    </varyants>
        </post>
```

I tried combining these two xml files using the OXYGEN XML program, but I could not succeed. After researching on the internet, I saw the XLS codes, but I do not know much about the subject. I have to merge two XML files. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join two XML files with a matching node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364362/how-to-join-two-xml-files-with-a-matching-node)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT is the right tool for this job; it's worth spending a bit of time reading up on XSLT, and if you get stuck, you can ask the question again saying exactly how far you got. Alternatively, if you simplify the example so there are only half a dozen elements rather than 40 or so, and if you explain what the merging rules are rather than leaving readers to reverse-engineer the rules from your example, then someone will probably be prepared to write the code for you, which you can then extrapolate to your real-world problem.

Note that there are several versions of XSLT. For merging and grouping problems like this, XSLT 2.0+ is a lot more powerful, but some commodity XSLT processors only support XSLT 1.0.